# Insert/constraints in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have problem with INSERTING or CONSTRAINT in SQL (Oracle DB).

I create table BOOKS(ID PK, TITLE, YEAR, PRICE, ID_AUTHOR FK, ID_PUBLISHER FK, ID_KIND FK), and then i tried to INSERT 18 rows in that table. Added 9 rows correctly but at tenth was this error:

```
INSERT INTO KSIAZKA 
VALUES 
(10, 'Visual Basic .NET i platforma .NET', 2000, 70.00, 7, 3, 9)
```

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.ID_AUTOR) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.'
```

I tried to insert 10 the same rows and 9 added correctly but the last one the error occured.

My question is - why can i insert only 9 rows? What can I do with that problem?

btw. I can write queries that provide me that constraints in table are correct.

I'm using Oracle 11g Express Edition and SQL Developer.

Comment: Well the error says it all: you are inserting a row with a value that has no corresponding PK value in the referenced table (author). Btw: you should ***NOT*** create tables as `SYSTEM`. Don't do it, create a regular user to work with.

Comment: If first value in INSERT (id) is 10 or more then there is an error. If I INSERT value 9 or 2 or 5 as ID in table BOOKS everything is fine...

Comment: You may have setup the foreign key constraint wrongly. Show us the design of table `KSIAZKA`.

Comment: I paste parts of DLL code:
CREATE TABLE KSIAZKA 
(
  ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, TYTUL VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, ROK NUMBER 
, CENA NUMBER(5, 2) 
, ID_AUTOR NUMBER 
, ID_WYDAWNICTWO NUMBER 
, ID_GATUNEK NUMBER 
, CONSTRAINT KSIAZKA_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE 
)
ALTER TABLE KSIAZKA
ADD CONSTRAINT ID_AUTOR FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES AUTOR (ID) ENABLE;

And the same code with other foreign keys (ID_WYDAWNICTWO and ID_GATUNEK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
 ADD CONSTRAINT ID_AUTOR FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES AUTOR (ID)
```

Your foreign key should be id_autor. Like that:

```
 ADD CONSTRAINT ID_AUTOR FOREIGN KEY(ID_AUTOR) REFERENCES AUTOR (ID)
```

Regards!

Comment: Thank you! 
I was create table by wizard in SQL Developer and I don't know what did wrong that table was create wrong (foreign key).

THANK YOU SO MUCH! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use explicit sintax (with column name):

```
INSERT INTO KSIAZKA (column_name1,column_name2,column_name3...)
VALUES 
(10, 'Visual Basic .NET i platforma .NET', 2000, 70.00, 7, 3, 9)
```

I think the columns order isn't ok.